# Problema com Banco de Dados MYSQL + PHP

Tags: php

Ao executar essa pagina, me retorna o seguinte erro.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function query() in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\admin\admin.php on line 6

Meu Codigo Php.

```
<?php

include("conexao.php");

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM snaps";
$con = $mysqli=query($consulta) or die($mysqli=error);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Codigo</td>
                <td>Nome</td>
                <td>SnapChat</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Data de Cadastro</td>
            </tr>
            <?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $dado["id"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["nome"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["snapc"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["email"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["created"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

E essa é meu Conexao.php

```
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "vertrigo";
$dbname = "snapsje";

//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
```

Comment: Você percebeu que você está fazendo `$mysqli=query` ao invés de `$mysqli->query`? Em `$mysqli=error` a mesma coisa. Erro de digitação. Aliás, o objeto `$mysqli` nem existe no seu código. Você definiu a conexão com o banco em `$conn`.

Comment: Sim, eu mudei o $mysqli->query, para $mysqli=query, pois quando deixo $mysqli->query, me retorna isso - Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in

Comment: Pois é, eu comentei sobre isso também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você está fazendo aqui `$mysqli=query()` é instanciando uma variável chamada `mysql` e atribuindo o valor retornado da função `query()`, do qual acredito que não exista no seu programa.

Para consertar tente desta maneira:

```
$con = $conn->query($consulta) or die($conn->error);
```

Ou dessa:

```
$con = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta) or die(mysqli_error);
```

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigado !

Comment: Caso a resposta esteja certa, por favor marque como correta.